# nvd3 chart - y-axis values not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I am creating a nvd3 chart.

```js
var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();
d3.select('#chart svg').datum([{
    "key": "A",
    "values": [{
        "x": "SADSA",
        "y": "4.0"
      },
      {
        "x": "FDDG",
        "y": "6.0"
      },
      {
        "x": "FF",
        "y": "4.15"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "B",
    "values": [{
        "x": "SADSA",
        "y": "20.0"
      },
      {
        "x": "FDDG",
        "y": "18.0"
      },
      {
        "x": "FF",
        "y": "19.45"
      }
    ]
  }
]).transition().duration(500).call(chart);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css">

<div id="chart" style="height: 200px;"><svg></svg></div>
```

I have y-axis values up to 20 but it's displaying up to 6 only (i.e ideal time and operational time y-axis values are not displaying correctly). Is there any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I did a misatke in my data format,changed data format like this.

```
 [
        {
            key:"A",
            values:[
                {
                x:"SADSA",
                y:4.0
                },
                {
                x:"FDDG",
                y:6.0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            key:"B",
            values:[
                {
                x:"SADSA",
                y:20.0
                },
                {
                x:"FDDG",
                y:18.0
                }
            ]
        }
        ]
```

Got expected result.